# How to debug php fatal errors in Silex Framework

Tags: php, debugging, silex

I wonder how can I see syntax errors like this (missing semicolon):

```
<?php
var_dump($app)
?>
```

This will cause a WSOD (white screen of death).

I tried to include a debug config file which look like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;

// Include the prod configuration
require __DIR__.'/prod.php';

// Enable PHP Error level
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');

// Enable debug mode
$app['debug'] = true;

// Handle fatal errors
ErrorHandler::register();

Debug::enable();
```

I included in composer json file:

"symfony/debug": "~2.3",

But still no change. What did I forgot?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\ErrorHandler;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\ExceptionHandler;

// set the error handling
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);
ErrorHandler::register();
if ('cli' !== php_sapi_name()) {
  ExceptionHandler::register();
}

// init application
$app = new Silex\Application();

// set debug mode
$app['debug'] = true

$app->run();
```

it's important to set the error handling before initialize the $app.

Answer (score 2):

Install Symfony/debug using `composer require symfony/debug` and add these lines before Silex\Application instance

```
use \Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler;
use \Symfony\Component\Debug\ExceptionHandler;
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
error_reporting(-1);
ErrorHandler::register();
ExceptionHandler::register();
```